# ssh login fails with timeout

Tags: ssh

I have a virtual server (A) at amazon from which i try to ssh to an other server (B). It fails with timeout.

On server B there is no rule for the IP of server A. Checked in IP tables, in the fail2ban and syslog too. When I just try to wget something it works.

From server A I can successfully login to other servers, and from other servers I also can successfully login to server B.

I do not know what's next. Please give me some tips.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a port/ip specific problem suggesting a fail2ban/firewall issue but if you have definitely checked both then there next step would be to analyze the traffic with tcpdump.

Comment: Can you help me with what to check exactly and how?